# Pinging a private IP from one private subnet to another private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC with 3 subnets.There is 1 public (WEB) and 2 private subnets (APP & DB). I have 2 instances each in each subnet.

I am able to ping DB Servers (say 10.0.3.1 & 10.0.3.2) from App Servers (10.0.2.1 & 10.0.2.2).

I have a requirement that, I have to use a private IP (say 10.0.3.33) in DB private subnet (IP range 10.0.3.0/24)  as a floating IP. It should not be associated with any of the running server in the DB Subnet.

I chose one IP (10.0.3.33) from the DB subnet and I can ping it from instances in DB subnet. But I am not able to ping that IP (10.0.3.33) from app servers (10.0.2.1 & 10.0.2.2).

I have  all traffic open for those private subnets.

Kindly help!!!

Regards,

Chandan

Comment: If you have an IP not associated with any running server, you shouldn't be able to ping it from anywhere.  I'm unclear what you are asking.

Comment: what is 10.0.3.33 bound to? if it's not bound to anything (server/interface) you should not be able to ping it and you probably are not interpreting the results of the ping correctly.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I am trying to ping an IP in a private subnet from another subnet. I have requirement such that, I cannot associate that IP to any instance.

Comment: @Mircea, I have associated 10.0.3.33 to an eni. Still not able to ping from 10.0.2.xx. However, I am able to ping 10.0.3.33 from 10.0.3.xx with or without associating with eni.